# sliding a new div over an older div by hovering over it is resulting in blinking

Tags: html, css

I want a div when being hovered over, another div to slide over it. I've got the new div to slide over, but whenever mouse starts hovering over the new div, it starts blinking

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: 33vw 33vw 33vw;
  grid-template-rows: 45vh 45vh 45vh;
  grid-column-gap: 0.33vw;
  grid-row-gap: 0.33vh;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.ProjectGrid-main {
  background-color: #282c34;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ProjectGrid-Image {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ProjectGrid-details {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.ProjectGrid-main :hover~.ProjectGrid-details {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class='ProjectGrid-main'>
    <div class='ProjectGrid-Image'>
      <img ref="image" src={} alt="" width="50%" height="75%" />
    </div>
    <div class='ProjectGrid-details'>
      <h1>Title1</h1>
      <p>Paragraph1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='ProjectGrid-main'>
    <div class='ProjectGrid-Image'>
      <img ref="image" src={} alt="" width="50%" height="75%" />
    </div>
    <div class='ProjectGrid-details'>
      <h1>Title2</h1>
      <p>Paragraph2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Herre's the Codepen https://codepen.io/Maskedman99/pen/NWPQKdd?editors=1100 Please try finding the solution only with CSS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the tilde combinator and let your `:hover` pseudo-class align with the projectgrid-main `.ProjectGrid-main:hover .ProjectGrid-details`

Using the combinator, it acts a condition to your effect. That condition is no longer true when your mouse is off the grid-main. It tries to retract, yet your mouse is still hovering over the  main grid, then it tries to extend itself(back and forth), and that's why you get the flicker.

IMO: It seems you want the other grid to overlay on the image and not squish the image. Use `position:relative` on the parent grid and `position:absolute` on the child, with a `right:`positioning. Also, set the parents `overflow` to hidden for this to work properly.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: stretch;
    grid-template-columns: 33vw 33vw 33vw;
    grid-template-rows: 45vh 45vh 45vh;
    grid-column-gap: 0.33vw;
    grid-row-gap: 0.33vh;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
  
  .ProjectGrid-main {
    /*changes here*/
    background-color: #282c34;
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: default;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .ProjectGrid-Image {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .ProjectGrid-details {
    /*changes here*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
    right:-100%;
    transition:.5s;
  }
  
  .ProjectGrid-main:hover .ProjectGrid-details {
    /*changes here*/
    right:0px;
    transition:.5s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
          
          <div class='ProjectGrid-main'>
            <div class='ProjectGrid-Image'>
              <img ref="image" src={} alt="" width="50%" height="75%"/>
            </div>
            <!--hover-->
            <div class='ProjectGrid-details'>
              <h1>Title1</h1>
              <p>Paragraph1</p>
            </div>  
            <!--hover-->
          </div>
        
          <div class='ProjectGrid-main'>
            <div class='ProjectGrid-Image'>
              <img ref="image" src={} alt="" width="50%" height="75%"/>
            </div>
            <div class='ProjectGrid-details'>
              <h1>Title2</h1>
              <p>Paragraph2</p>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The space between `.ProjectGrid-main` and `:hover` also messed things up on my Firefox for Mac.